# How does a dragon with plated tongue hunt?

Tags: creature-design, dragons, senses

Beyond the thick forest lies a colossal winged flightless dragon with a unique distinct feature that is its plated tongue!
According to legend it seems to prefer diseased humans and animals that will soon be on their death bed, but would never sink its fangs into a healthy individual.
A folk song suggests it may have had myopia or even poor eyesight so it has difficulty telling if someone is in good shape or terminally ill. That's why I am guessing the trick may lie in its plated tongue which can somehow detect potential prey, much like how a snake picks up body odours from the air. One thing that's sure is that the dragon wouldn't accidentally bite its own tongue because my great grandma told me it can't say any tongue twister at all.

My question then is how does this dragon with plated tongue hunt for prey?

Comment: there's that ambiguity between "it seems to _prefer_ diseased etc" (which indicates a "matter of preference" which, if not met, there could be other choices the dragon may make) and "would never sink it's fangs on a healthy individual". Or is it that, failing to find the _preferred_ diet, the dragon falls into vegetarianism? (or even begins relying on photosynthesis? Or maybe chemosynthesis near a volcanic vent?) Those details matter for the structure and composition of he tongue plate, which will inevitable impact on the capabilities of the said tongue to act itself as the detector.

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi: I'm planning an expedition to find this dragon for study so now all details are eyewitnesses accounts. So we take their words for it until a specimen is found.

Comment: Well then, maybe the study will reveal something about his detection capabilities, until then all the answers are speculative.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you mean by a "plated" tongue.

Answer (score 1):

## Loreal pit

Snakes have "pits" that work as sensorial organs, helping them detect the temperature and vibrations of things close to them.
As the temperature and movement of dying animals are different (most of the time) than healthy ones that may help a creature to figure out what prey is safe to eat.

Comment: Nothing better than frozen meat, right? ;)

Answer (score -2):

The dragons with plated tongue don't hunt for their diet anymore.

They just took a paid subscription from the Death, for "ringing that bell" notifications in advance of "bell tolling" events.

In the world today, Death can no longer provide bona fide services, the court decided it needs to be a profitable enterprise and it needs to keep the interest of its shareholders above anything else (and no, [this is not speculative](https://www.lexisnexis.com/community/casebrief/p/casebrief-ebay-domestic-holdings-inc-v-newmark)).

Remember, kids, once more: "if you're not paying for the product, you are the merchandise".